# Найти пропущенные даты

Tags: sql, sql-server

Имеется результат выборки:

```
link    date_change
15      2018-09-30 00:00:03.740
15      2018-09-30 00:00:03.740
15      2018-09-11 14:54:15.403
15      2018-09-11 14:51:49.713
15      2018-09-07 11:52:08.710
15      2018-09-07 11:45:39.983
15      2018-09-07 10:33:38.367
15      2018-09-07 09:45:16.723
15      2018-09-06 14:27:54.007
15      2018-09-06 14:11:09.190
16      2018-09-06 09:28:39.890
16      2018-09-04 18:45:37.693
16      2018-09-03 15:15:44.907
```

Необходимо найти пропуски дат для каждого "link", в результате получив что-то вроде:

```
link   cnt     date_1      date_2
15     19      2018-09-11  2018-09-30
15     4       2018-09-07  2018-09-11
16     2       2018-09-04  2018-09-06
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.link,
                DATEDIFF(day, 
                         CAST(t1.date_change AS DATE), 
                         CAST(t2.date_change AS DATE)) cnt,
                CAST(t1.date_change AS DATE) date_1, 
                CAST(t2.date_change AS DATE) date_2
FROM test t1, test t2
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, t1.date_change, t2.date_change) > 1
  AND t1.link = t2.link
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM test t3
                  WHERE t1.link = t3.link
                    AND t1.date_change < t3.date_change
                    AND t3.date_change < t2.date_change)
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=90c8520bb5d445b18345d637b6ff4764)

А по-хорошему - сразу преобразовать дату-время в дату (и DISTINCT) в секции WITH.

PS. На реальных данных, вероятно, придётся везде в показанном запросе все вхождения date_change изменить на CAST к дате, а не только в выходном наборе.